# How to get wordpress category slug including Parent

Tags: wordpress

I have this code below to show get the slug of the current category, I also want it to get the parent of that category if there is one…

```
<?php
 if (is_category( )) {
   $cat = get_query_var('cat');
   $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
   echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.xxxxx.com/'. $yourcat->slug.'/">';
 }
 ?>
```

I want the parent category to then fit into this with the / as above. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following code to get the parent category slug:

```
<?php
 if (is_category( )) {
   $cat = get_query_var('cat');
   $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
   echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.xxxxx.com/'. $yourcat->slug.'/">';


     $category_parent_id = $yourcat->parent;
     $category_parent = get_term( $category_parent_id, 'category' );
    echo $parent_category_slug = $category_parent->slug;

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would that look when combined with the above and all put together?

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted the parent to show in the:
   echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.xxxxx.com/'. $yourcat->slug.'/">';

So if there is a parent it shows in there with a / after it, however if there is no parent then it doesn't show and there is no /?

Comment: you can do that easily by checking 
if ( $category_parent_id != 0 ) {
}

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I'm not sure what the code should look like to do this?